# What is the use of Magento 2.2.6 product image cache?

Tags: magento2, product-images, cache, magento2.2.6

I have some points regarding the Product Image Cache to discuss with you.

1. I have `created a product` from the Magento admin panel.
2. After creating the product, I have `uploaded two of the product images` (same images but different sizes) to that product.
3. I have `downloaded the images from the storefront of our site` and see that both the images have the same size (but originally I have uploaded two different sizes).
4. When I have investigated this issue, I came to know that the `Images in the storefront are coming from the product cache`.
5. Now, my doubt is that how this product image cache has generated?.

Please guide me.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Which Magento version?

Comment: @SohelRana Magento 2.2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload image for product with specific image sizes, like 1200x1200 and you use it on thumbnail with the size 60x60 and small image like 200x200 and large image like 600x600. It creates cache images according to your given size.

The benefit of this is, user will not suffer in rendering large size images all over the website, it will show small image or thumbnail image on the web page, and that results with the high performance of the website.

Hope you find your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand Magento serves storefront images from cache. But, Is it a good thing to use Image optimizer plugin to optimize the images size?. Because,  In my case, we have a lot of products on our website and for each product image, the file size is huge.

Comment: Magento resizes images but you still need image optimizer like google page speed etc. And yes, it is a drawback of magento that it uses high space to store images, i.e, for original image and multiple resize images of each product. But still it is a good feature

Comment: Yes, It's a drawback in Magento. I have one more query, Is the Storefront only shows the images from the cache?

Comment: Mostly it shows images from cache, but when you apply zoom on product page it would show original images. But still if you used resized images for zoom image then it will also show images from cache

Comment: Did you find it useful?

Comment: Yes, so far your information is helpful for me. Finally, please tell me how to find the image is an original one instead of cache image. I have marked your information as an answer so that it will reach others as well.

Comment: Thanks @Magentovsmarttec
Lets say you have an image URL catalog/product/cache/ab724d95533c5f8b6756896b159d317e/1/1/1115830-1.jpg
If you want to get real image from this URL you need to remove **/cache/random_number/** from URL and you will get your original image.
But for frontend, you can't do anything, magento will resize images according to specified sizes and use it on frontend with cache URLs.

Comment: @Shohaib Munir We have almost 300 products on our site. For each product, we have created the images. Let say, the average size of images for one product is 4MB. But as far as I understand, cache serves the Storefront images and the cache images are less in size compared to the original image size. In this case, can I directly upload the created images without using any compression? or is it good to use a compression tool to compress the images before uploading them to site?

Comment: Yes, resized images would be less in size as compared to the original, but still it is good if you optimize images and then upload on magento. By doing this your resized images would be much more optimized

Comment: Here's I'm facing difficult to understand the process. For the testing purpose, I have uploaded 2 of the images(Original and compressed) to a product. Then, I have downloaded both the images from the frontend but I can see that the size of both images are same. How the size of both the images are same? I hope you understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: May be when magento resizes images it also compressing it, the point is you are getting compressed images at the end

Comment: But for the main image, you need to compress it by yourself so that in zoom functionality user will get optimized images

Comment: I see and I really appreciate your comments because now I understand what the product image cache is. 
By the way, What you're referring here as the main image?

Comment: Main image is the image that you are uploading

Comment: Thanks for that. I have tried to check the file size of the image while zooming but without success. Can you please point me out how to check the file size of the image when we zoom it?

Comment: Is it possible to check the file size of the image when we zoom it?